# "Right Alt" key does not work same as "Left Alt" key

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I've set up the mic mute/unmute shortcut to `ctrl+alt+M`. With *left alt* it works as intended, but with *right alt* it does not work.

Now the `M` key being very close to *right alt*, I prefer the shortcut to work with *right alt*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, the default configuration of **Alternate Characters key** (special characters which can't be reached by shift) is set to *Right Alt*, which was causing the problem.

To fix it, simply go to `Settings` then `Keyboard Shortcuts` and change the `Alternate Characters key` (present at the top) to something else, such as `Right Super`.